# How to replace default info window marker with custom info window marker in map compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-maps

I would like to customise my info window marker of map in compose. My new info window marker is different in shape. I couldn't find proper solution to replace default one with new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This support is already available on the latest version of [android-maps-compose](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose). From the documentation, you can do something similar to:

```kotlin
MarkerInfoWindow(
    state = yourMarker,
    icon = yourMarkerIcon,
    title = yourMarkerTitle
) { marker ->
    // Implement the custom info window here
    Column {
        Text(marker.title ?: "Default Marker Title", color = Color.Red)
        Text(marker.snippet ?: "Default Marker Snippet", color = Color.Red)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing the updated answer,
you can add you customized window in content parama

```
MarkerInfoWindow(
 state = yourMarker,
 title = yourMarkerTitle,
 icon = yourMarkerIcon,
 content = {
           // Implement the custom info window here
            Column {
            Text(marker.title ?: "Default Marker Title", color = Color.Red)
            Text(marker.snippet ?: "Default Marker Snippet", color = Color.Red)
           })
```